# Ubuntu server 22.04 on Raspberry Pi not picking up both attached disks

Tags: server, hardware, raspberrypi

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS server is not picking up both USB attached SSDs on my Raspberry Pi 4b.

My Pi has two USB 3.x ports and I'm using two USB to SATA cables to connect 2 x 1TB Samsung 870 QVO SATA III 2.5 SSDs.

When both SSDs are attached `sudo fdisk -l` only ever shows `/dev/sda`.

To eliminate hardware issues, I've tested every combination of port/disk/cable and they all work.

I've tried `sudo partprobe` but no dice.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Edit: I've just found out that plugging in one of the disks while the Pi is powered on causes both to now show up!

Comment: If you're powering the disks from the Pi, check for sufficient electrical power.

Comment: RPi might not be sufficient enough to power those devices together without you using external power sources.  It's most likely that the Pi doesn't have the power output necessary to properly power one or both disks.

Comment: Your observation (that staggered disk startups works) confirms the "insufficient power" hypothesis. Disks draw more power when they start (going from 0 RPM to 3600 RPM), doing them both at the same time draws 2xstartup power. Doing them at different times doesn't overload the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

You should connect **both** external disks to external power sources, because the Pi is not going to have the capacity to provide that kind of power to external devices like hard drives and spinning HDDs.

The RPi has a very *low* total power output capacity on the USB controllers on the board, and as you plugged *one* of the disks in to external power when the Pi was on and both showed up, this supports the insufficient power hypothesis.

I would not try and have the Pi power two USB-powered adapters/disks without an external power provider because the Pi is designed to be relatively low power and isn't as powerful with its power outputs.

Comment: Here's my case, btw -https://shop.inux3d.com/en/home/53-99-the-terrapi-q-a-quiet-terrapi.html#/10-color-red/26-ssd-single

Comment: @MikeW Just because your *case* lets you connect something or hook something up doesn't mean that **the Pi itself** can handle it.  It's not up to us to decide what you use your SSDs for or your Pi.  All you know is what we know, that connecting two USB 3.0 external drives and trying to use the Pi to power both is not enough to power either device and you are restricted to only one or two such drives.  They *do* make enclosures (not just adapters) that accept external power supplies if you *wanted* to go that route, but what you do with the devices now is not our call/suggestion.